# How to check if a macro exists in CMake

Tags: cmake

How do I correctly check if a macro is defined in CMake?

```
macro(foo)
    message("foo")
endmacro()

if(<what goes here?>)
    foo()
endif()
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [if command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html) supports a `COMMAND` clause for that purpose:

```
if(COMMAND foo)
    foo()
endif()
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [MACROS](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#prop_dir%3aMACROS) property [for a given directory](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#command%3aget_directory_property).

```
get_directory_property(DEFINED_MACROS DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} MACROS)
list(FIND DEFINED_MACROS "foo" MACRO_INDEX)
if(MACRO_INDEX EQUAL -1)
    # macro foo does not exist
else(MACRO_INDEX EQUAL -1)
    # macro foo exists
endif(MACRO_INDEX EQUAL -1)
```